# DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'DocID'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

i try this query to view documents only for those who uploaded through their account means 
user only view their own documents
query

```
 ALTER procedure [dbo].[dddddd]
   @userid int
   as                     
   SELECT DISTINCT DocumentInfo.DocID as DocumentID ,
    dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName as DocumentName,
    dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile as FileUploaded,
    dbo.DocType.DocType as Document,
    dbo.Department.DepType as Department ,
    dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType AS ApproveID
    FROM dbo.DocumentInfo
    inner JOIN dbo.DocType ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocTypeID=dbo.DocType.DocTypeID
    inner JOIN dbo.Department ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID=dbo.Department.DepID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.ApproveType ON    
     dbo.ApproveType.approveid=dbo.DocumentInfo.ApproveID   
    LEFT    
    OUTER JOIN
    Approval a ON a.DocID = a.DocID
    JOIN
    ApproveType at ON at.ApproveID = ISNULL(a.Approveid, 3)  where UserID=@userid
```

but it shows me error

```
DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'DocID'."
```

in this line

```
  <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"DocID") %></td>
```

where is the mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no DocID being returned in your query as you have aliased the column to be `DocumentID`.

Change to this instead:

```
 <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"DocumentID") %></td>
```

Also is your `left outer join` correct? You seem to be using the same table on both sides of the query. More of an observation.